# Tic-tac-toe code help improve

Tags: c#

This is the code i have to check the players win for the tic tact toe game. It is a very long if statement that can be improved. The board is made of 9 picture boxes.I am a c# beginner.

```
pBox.Image = Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage();
//check for wins


if (pbxSquare0.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() && //horizontal
    pbxSquare1.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare2.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage()

    ||
    pbxSquare3.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare4.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare5.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage()

    ||
    pbxSquare6.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare7.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare8.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage()

    ||
    pbxSquare0.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() && //vertical
    pbxSquare3.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare6.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage()

    ||
    pbxSquare1.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare4.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare7.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() 

    ||
    pbxSquare2.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare5.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare8.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage()
    ||
    pbxSquare0.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() && //diagnonal
    pbxSquare4.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare8.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage()
    ||
    pbxSquare2.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare4.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage() &&
    pbxSquare6.Image == Player.players[Player.playerTurn].getImage())

{
    //playerturn is the winner
    MessageBox.Show(playerturn + "wins");
}
```

Comment: If you want suggestion to your code, post this on Code Review, not on Stack Overflow

Comment: Download a copy of Resharper and run an Inspection on the code; it might give you several good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a 2-dimensional array for your game. Possibly with an enum type.

```
 enum FieldState { Empty, Player1, Player2 };
private FieldState[,] _gameField = new FieldState[3,3];
```

If there is a turn, update your game field accordingly. Also assign the pictures.
If you have your gamestate in an array, its much easier to find the win condition because you can loop.

```
private bool win(FieldState player){
   return winHorizontal(player) || winVertical(player) || winDiagonal(player);
}

private bool winHorizontal(FieldState player){
   for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        bool win = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
           win &= _gameField[x,y] == player;
        if (win) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```